How to navigate between pages using Selenium?
I'm trying to webscrape this website with car listings - cargurus.com. Specifically, I'm trying to scrape details from ferraris on sale. I've been able to get it to work, at least the first page. However, it despite it telling me it's moved on to the next page of entries, it keeps giving me repeated results.
I've tried a) updating the link of the page it's looking at
def __init__(self, car_make: str) -> None:
     self.car_make = car_make
     self.base_url = f"https://www.cargurus.com/Cars/l-Used-{car_make}-m25"

def load_page(self, page_number: int):
    url = f"{self.base_url}?resultsPage={page_number}"
    self.driver.get(url)
    print(f"\nAccessing URL: {url}")  # Print the URL at the top of each page scan

    # Wait for the page to load completely
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'cargurus-listing-search'))
    )

and b) Used selenium to try and simulate clicking the next page button once all entries are scraped on the current page:
def click_next_page(self):
    try:
        # Wait for the "Next Page" button to be clickable
        next_button = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[aria-labelledby="bottomPaginationNext"]'))
        )
        next_button.click()
        print("Clicked the 'Next Page' button.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to click 'Next Page' button. Msg: {e}")
        logging.error(f"Failed to click 'Next Page' button. Msg: {e}")

Yet, when I run the code (which i wrote so that when repeated entries are found, it auto-stops for time's sake) it still sees same entries (car listings)
I have no idea how to proceed.
This is my full code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
from typing import List
import csv
import logging
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

@dataclass
class Car:
    link: str
    full_name: str
    hp: str
    engine: str
    year: int
    mileage: str
    price: int

class CarScraper:
    def __init__(self, car_make: str) -> None:
        self.car_make = car_make
        self.base_url = f"https://www.cargurus.com/Cars/l-Used-{car_make}-m25"

        # Set up Chrome options
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument("--headless")  # Run Chrome in headless mode
        options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

        # Path to chromedriver
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'), options=options)
        self.processed_links = set()  # Set to keep track of processed car links
        self.processed_pages = set()  # Set to keep track of processed page numbers

    def load_page(self, page_number: int):
        url = f"{self.base_url}?resultsPage={page_number}"
        self.driver.get(url)
        print(f"\nAccessing URL: {url}")  # Print the URL at the top of each page scan

        # Wait for the page to load completely
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'cargurus-listing-search'))
        )

    def get_page_source(self) -> str:
        return self.driver.page_source

    def extract_cars_from_page(self, soup: BeautifulSoup) -> List[Car]:
        offers_table = soup.find('div', id='cargurus-listing-search')

        if offers_table is None:
            print("Failed to find the offers table on the page.")
            logging.error("Failed to find the offers table on the page.")
            print(soup.prettify())  # Print the prettified HTML for debugging
            return []

        print("Found offers table.")

        # Navigate through nested divs to find car entries
        nested_container = offers_table.find('div', class_='pecvNo')
        if nested_container is None:
            print("Failed to find the nested container.")
            logging.error("Failed to find the nested container.")
            return []

        car_entries_container = nested_container.find('div', class_='Km1Vfz')
        if car_entries_container is None:
            print("Failed to find the car entries container.")
            logging.error("Failed to find the car entries container.")
            return []

        car_entries = car_entries_container.find_all('div', class_='pazLTN')
        print(f"Found {len(car_entries)} car entries.")  # Debugging line

        list_of_cars = []
        for car in car_entries:
            try:
                link_element = car.find('a', href=True)
                link = link_element.get('href', 'N/A') if link_element else 'N/A'
                
                # Skip if this link has already been processed
                if link in self.processed_links:
                    continue
                
                self.processed_links.add(link)

                full_name_element = car.find('h4')
                full_name = full_name_element.get('title', 'N/A') if full_name_element else 'N/A'
                
                # Safely split full_name to get the year and the model
                split_name = full_name.split()
                year = int(split_name[0]) if split_name and split_name[0].isdigit() else 0
                model_name = " ".join(split_name[1:]) if len(split_name) > 1 else 'N/A'

                mileage_element = car.find('p', class_='us1dS iK3Zj _erOpv kIL3VY', attrs={'data-testid': 'srp-tile-mileage'})
                mileage_text = mileage_element.text.strip() if mileage_element else 'N/A'

                price_element = car.find('h4', class_='us1dS i5dPf SOf0Fe')
                price_text = price_element.text.strip().replace("$", "").replace(",", "") if price_element else '0'

                description_element = car.find('p', class_='us1dS iK3Zj _erOpv kIL3VY', attrs={'data-testid': 'seo-srp-tile-engine-display-name'})
                description_text = description_element.text.strip() if description_element else 'N/A'

                # Split the description into hp and engine
                if 'hp' in description_text:
                    hp, engine = description_text.split(' hp', 1)
                    hp = hp.strip()  # Ensure there are no leading/trailing spaces
                    engine = engine.strip()  # Remove any leading/trailing spaces from the engine part
                else:
                    hp = 'N/A'
                    engine = 'N/A'

                car_data = Car(
                    link="https://www.cargurus.com" + link,
                    full_name=model_name,
                    hp=hp,
                    engine=engine,
                    year=year,
                    mileage=mileage_text,
                    price=int(price_text)
                )
                list_of_cars.append(car_data)
                print(f"Extracted car: {car_data}")  # Debugging line
                logging.info(f"Extracted car: {car_data}")
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error(f"Failed to gather car. Msg: {e}")
                print(f"Failed to gather car. Msg: {e}")
        return list_of_cars

    def click_next_page(self):
        try:
            # Wait for the "Next Page" button to be clickable
            next_button = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[aria-labelledby="bottomPaginationNext"]'))
            )
            next_button.click()
            print("Clicked the 'Next Page' button.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed to click 'Next Page' button. Msg: {e}")
            logging.error(f"Failed to click 'Next Page' button. Msg: {e}")

    def quit_driver(self):
        if self.driver:
            self.driver.quit()

def write_to_csv(cars: List[Car]) -> None:
    try:
        with open("cargurus_ferrari.csv", mode="w", newline='') as f:
            fieldnames = [
                "link",
                "full_name",
                "hp",
                "engine",
                "year",
                "mileage",
                "price",
            ]
            writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            writer.writeheader()
            for car in cars:
                writer.writerow(asdict(car))
    except IOError as e:
        print(f"Failed to write to CSV file. Msg: {e}")

def scrape_all_pages():
    make = "Ferrari"  # Adjust this as needed
    scraper = CarScraper(make)
    all_cars = []

    page_number = 1
    while True:
        print(f"Scraping page {page_number}...")
        scraper.load_page(page_number)
        page_source = scraper.get_page_source()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, "html.parser")

        # Extract cars from the current page
        cars = scraper.extract_cars_from_page(soup)

        if not cars:
            print("No more new cars found or failed to extract cars. Ending scraping.")
            logging.info("No more new cars found or failed to extract cars. Ending scraping.")
            break

        all_cars.extend(cars)
        print(f"Number of cars found on page {page_number}: {len(cars)}")
        logging.info(f"Number of cars found on page {page_number}: {len(cars)}")

        # Track processed pages
        scraper.processed_pages.add(page_number)

        # Click the "Next Page" button
        scraper.click_next_page()
        page_number += 1
        time.sleep(5)  # Be polite and avoid hitting the server too hard

    # Save all collected cars to CSV
    write_to_csv(all_cars)
    print("All cars saved to cargurus_ferrari.csv")
    logging.info("All cars saved to cargurus_ferrari.csv")

    # Clean up
    scraper.quit_driver()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scrape_all_pages()


You could vary the resultsPage value from 1 by 1 until such time as the paging button is disabled like this:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions


URL = "https://www.cargurus.com/Cars/l-Used-Ferrari-m25#resultsPage={}"
SELECTOR = By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[aria-labelledby='bottomPaginationNext']"

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless=new')
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

with webdriver.Chrome(options) as driver:
    page = 1
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    while True:
        url = URL.format(page)
        print(url)
        try:
            driver.get(url)
            # process page content here
            button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(SELECTOR))
            if button.get_attribute("disabled") is not None:
                break
        except Exception as e:
            break
        page += 1

Another option is to click the page forward button (providing it's not disabled) then wait for the URL to change:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions


BUTTON_SELECTOR = By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[aria-labelledby='bottomPaginationNext']"

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless=new')
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

with webdriver.Chrome(options) as driver:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    driver.get("https://www.cargurus.com/Cars/l-Used-Ferrari-m25")
    while True:
        current = driver.current_url
        print(current)
        try:
            # process page here
            button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(BUTTON_SELECTOR))
            if button.get_attribute("disabled") is not None:
                break
            button.click()
            wait.until(EC.url_changes(current))
        except Exception as e:
            break

NOTE: You could use EC.element_to_be_clickable when considering whether (or not) to click the button. However, this is slow because once the button is disabled, that EC condition will result in a timeout. It's faster to identify the button and checks its disabled attribute
